# Preselect a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to preselect a value in my select but there is nothing, why is this?

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJXbrxOe1V4nTrMaznmb?p=preview)

```
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.cardSelect = [
      {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'white', shade:'light'},
      {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
    ];
    $scope.card = $scope.cardSelect[2]; // red
  }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`

```
<select data-ng-model="card" ng-options="card.name for card in cardSelect">
```

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/51uBAwkTHpnCGCXP9x8R?p=preview)

Comment: Probably worth pointing out why the original didn't work.  The value of each option was the shade property but the value on the scope was the third card object which isn't equal to just the shade property.